# MongoDB Connection Refused with vmc-tunnel-plugin

Tags: cloud-foundry

Maybe i am not understanding this correctly but here is how i am attempting to use the vmc tunnel.

note: MongoDB service is running and working fine verified with my vmc pushed nodejs app

I am attempting to access the mongodb using the mongodb url from a remote server

I created the tunnel on my local macbook and received the connection info

sudo vmc tunnel mongodb-1234 none

Service connection info:
  username : 12345
  password : 12345
  name     : db
  url      : mongodb://12345:12345@172.30.48.71:25283/db

on my remote server I am using the C# mongdb driver and used the url given to connect but my connection times out.

What am I missing?

Error message:
Unable to connect to server 172.30.48.71:25283: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 172.30.48.71:25283.

Comment: Do yo u must use vmc for using mongodb on cloudfoundry?

Answer (score 2):

The connection information returned by "vmc tunnel" can only be used either by the application on Cloud Foundry bound to the service or by the local tunnel on the machine running VMC.

When you create a tunnel, vmc opens a port (normally 10000) on your machine which tunnels through to the instance running on Cloud Foundry. You can use this port on your local machine to connect to MongoDB but there is no way of connecting to a service instance from a node external to CloudFoundry.com or the machine running VMC.